# C# how to check n numbers of x (mod operator?) in a list

Tags: c#

I want to be able to control the sequence of entries in a list. The first five entries should read "A", the following two should read "B", then the next five "A", next two "B" and so on. I just can't quite get the logic right to be able to do this.

I seem to run into trouble where both "A" and "B" are divisible by their weight. In this code you can see this when you have 10 x A and 2 x B. My logic says the next should be an "A" when really, I want the next two to be "B" to give me a total of 10 x A, 4 x B at which point, it should be back to reporting A as the next in sequence.

My example code to get started is as follows, just add more "a" or more "b" to the data variable to test it;

```
var aWeight = 5;
var bWeight = 2; 

var data = new string[] {"a", "a", "a", "a", "a"}; 

var aCount = data.Count(x => x == "a"); 
var bCount = data.Count(x => x == "b"); 

//aCount.Dump(); 
//bCount.Dump(); 

if(aCount % aWeight == 0) 
{
    if(aCount % aWeight == 0 && bCount % bWeight == 0 && bCount > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Next is A! - pos 1"); 
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Next is B! - pos 2"); 
}
else if(bCount % bWeight == 0) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Next is A! - pos 3" ); 
}
```

Comment: *In this code you can see this when you have 10 x A and 2 x B* => how?

Comment: I've seen this question before :) is this from a interview test?

Comment: @Thomas Ayoub If you take the code and run it in either LINQPad or VS and append to data i.e. var data = new string[] {"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b"};

Comment: @fubo no, but I guess it would be a good one! I'm trying to add some logic to what I'm displaying in various views from my controller. But I've broken my problem down to the bare minimum to try make it easier for people to understand without having to trudge through it all, this is the essence of the problem I have.

Comment: Not sure if we can understand the question from your explanation as you may not have understood the problem yourself?

Comment: @Janne Matikainen using only the count of a's or b's in a given list, how do I ensure the next one I am going to add is either an A or a B. That's literally the problem. For every 5 A's, I need to add 2 B's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of what you want, you can check the ratios of 5 to 2 versus your `aCount` to `bCount` as well. If they are the same, then you want an `a` next.

Change your if statement to contain a check for the ratios between the indirect ratios that already exist for aWeight, bWeight and aCount, bCount. I honestly cannot tell if you have an understanding of the question itself, but on my judgement I'm giving you the benefit of the doubt.

Also, your second check for `if(aCount % aWeight == 0)` I took out because it's redundant.

```
if (aCount % aWeight == 0)
{
    var weightRatio = ((double)aWeight/bWeight);
    var countRatio = ((double)aCount / bCount);
    if (bCount % bWeight == 0 && bCount > 0 && (weightRatio == countRatio))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Next is A! - pos 1");
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Next is B! - pos 2");
}
else if (bCount % bWeight == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Next is A! - pos 3");
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
List<Tuple<int, string> > repetitions =new List<Tuple<int, string>>()
{
    new Tuple<int, string>(5, "a"),
    new Tuple<int, string>(2, "b")
};

int numberOfElements = 15;
int currentCount = 0;
int currentIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfElements; i++)
{
    if (currentCount >= repetitions.ElementAt(currentIndex).Item1)
    {
        currentCount = 0;
        // Switch to next element
        if (++currentIndex > repetitions.Count - 1)
        {
            // Reset
            currentIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    Console.Out.WriteLine(repetitions.ElementAt(currentIndex).Item2);
    currentCount++;
}
```

Which will output:

> aaaaabbaaaaabbaa